# Oauth2 google-api-ruby-client: How to set Approval Prompt to Auto?

Tags: ruby, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-plus

*Question*: 
How to set the Approval Prompt to Auto?    It defaults to 'approval_prompt=force'

*Code*:
I am setting up the client like this.

```
   @client = Google::APIClient.new(
     :authorization => :oauth_2,
     :host => 'www.googleapis.com',
     :http_adapter => HTTPAdapter::NetHTTPAdapter.new
   )   
   @client.authorization.client_id = 'xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
   @client.authorization.client_secret = 'xxxx'
```

*Context*:  Google OAuth2

*Client Library*:  google-api-ruby-client

*Reference*: Same question for the php client :
[Google+ OAuth API store and retrieve tokens after first login and authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101551/google-oauth-api-store-and-retrieve-tokens-after-first-login-and-authorization?rq=1)

Signet Documentation. I can't find the approval_prompt setter
http://signet.rubyforge.org/api/Signet/OAuth2/Client.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem.

I wrote a separate helper method that will generate the Google OAuth URI

```
def build_auth_uri
return @client.authorization.authorization_uri(
 :approval_prompt => :auto
).to_s
```

end

Next, instead of referring to Google OAuth URI directly in my view, I called the helper.

That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem:

In /app/views/devise/shared/_links.haml (it's similar for _links.erb):

```
- if devise_mapping.omniauthable?
  - resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider|
    - if provider == :google_oauth2
      = link_to "Sign in with Google", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider, approval_prompt: :auto)
    - else
      = link_to "Sign in with #{provider.to_s.titleize}", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider)
    %br/
```

EDIT: Even easier: Add this to your devise.rb or omniauth.rb initializer (in /config/initializers):

```
provider :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_KEY"], ENV["GOOGLE_SECRET"], {
  approval_prompt: "auto"
}
```

Check the documentation [here](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) for more info.